# Access Violation Writing Location in my simple c++ code

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

struct car
{
    string name, model;
    int year;   
};

void search_car(int CarYear)
{
    cout<<"1";
    ifstream in;
    cout<<"2";
    car c1;
    cout<<"3";
    in.open("Cars.txt",ios::binary|ios::in);
    cout<<"4"<<endl;
    while(!in.eof())
    {
        cout<<" 5";
        in.read((char *) &c1, sizeof(car));
        cout<<" 6.Car Year: "<<c1.year<<endl;
        if(c1.year == CarYear)
        {
            cout<<" 7>>> ";
            cout<<c1.name<<" "<<c1.model<<" "<<c1.year;
            cout<<" <<<8"<<endl;
        }
    }
    cout<<" 9";
    in.close();
    cout<<" 10";    
}

void main()
{
    car c[100];
    int carNum, menuAct = 0, CarYear = -1, cycle = 1;
    ofstream out;
    while (cycle == 1)
    {
        //clrscr();
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"1.Enter New car"<<endl<<"2.Search"<<endl<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
        cin>>menuAct;
        cout<<"   Menu Action: "<<menuAct<<endl;
        if(menuAct == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Num OF Cars: ";
            cin>>carNum;
            out.open("Cars.txt",ios::binary|ios::out|ios::app);
            for(int i = 0; i < carNum; i++)
            {
                cout<<"Enter Name OF Car: ";
                cin>>c[i].name;
                cout<<"Enter model OF Car: ";
                cin>>c[i].model;
                cout<<"Enter year OF Car: ";
                cin>>c[i].year;     
                out.write((char *) &c[i], sizeof(car));
            }
            out.close();
        }
        else if(menuAct == 2)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Car Year: ";
            cin>>CarYear;
            cout<<" 0";
            //cout<<" Y: "<<CarYear;
            search_car(CarYear);
            cout<<" 11";
            //menuAct = 0;
        }
        else if(menuAct == 3)
        {
            cycle = 0;
        }
    }   
}
```

Error:

http://s3.picofile.com/file/7580464836/cpp_err11.jpg

**What is happened?** 
I`m used some cout to trace what is happening and code is stopped at  number 10.

Also last car is printed twice!!!

Comment: first off, void main should NEVER be used under any circumstance, main always return type int.

Comment: Can anyone help me?
What is these minuses of my question?!

Comment: Thank you Need4Sleep.
Is in my code any other logical ... error?

Comment: I would suggest that you narrow it down to a small, simple self-contained program that reproduces the error. Nobody wants to debug someone else's wall of code.

Comment: eof loops can cause you some trouble, which is why your last car is being printed twice. Here is an example of a proper EOF loop i wrote up used commonly http://pastebin.com/mYcncKCj

Comment: but this error in a simple code is not unusual?!
I`m confused.
I cant` get rid of that really.
@juanchopanza

Comment: Thank you man for your attention :)
It was in my mind to use this technique to avoid twice result in last structure of file..
It seems to be the only way. @Need4Sleep

Comment: let me know if the solution i gave works.

Comment: @Need4Sleep It's a start, but the real issue here is reading garbage data in the std::string's data member. Yuck.

Comment: Thank you Mr @NicholasWilson very much :)
Your Answer was perfect.
My problem is resolved.
This site users seems pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not surprised you're having problems! You're saving the bytes of the struct literally, and then when you read them back from the file, you're hoping you'll get a std::string back again. It doesn't work that way at all.

The problem is that the car struct doesn't contain all the data it references: the std::string members are actually just pointers to a dynamic array containing the actual string data. You're writing out the car structures as raw bytes, so the strings are never going to file. There's no way they could ever be read back out of it.

Worse, when you read the structs back in, you're setting the pointers in the std::string to garbage values. You can't possibly hope that the memory they happen to point to contains what you want.

You need to define serialisation functions for the car struct, that send it to an outstream using a deep copy, and read it back in safely. Never write raw pointer values to file.

#### Example code

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const car& c) {
    return os << c.name << endl << c.model << endl << c.year << endl;
}
istream& operator >>(istream& is, car& c) {
    is >> c.name;
    is >> c.model;
    is >> c.year;
    return is;
}
```

Change `in.read((char *) &c1, sizeof(car));` to `in >> c1;`.

Change `out.write((char *) &c[i], sizeof(car));` to `out << c[i];`.

Much neater! PS. As an excellent general rule, don't ever cast to `char*` until you understand what it does and how strings are handled!